# How can I connect to SQLServer running on VirtualBox from my host Macbook

Tags: sql-server, macos, virtualbox

I want to run SQLServer on my Mac but I can't do it natively.  How can I host a SQLServer with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) and connect to it from my MacBook for local development?

Comment: This is an "answer my own question" question, so please forgive the broad looking description of the question, I am just trying to catch as many Google searches as possible.

Comment: For the record, 3 people voted to migrate this post to Super User. However the system requires 4 people to vote to migrate for the migration to take place.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

1. Download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org)
2. Download a Windows 10 ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10ISO)
3. Create a new Windows 10 VM with VirtualBox.  When it asks for the "Virtual Optical Disk File", point it to the ISO download from Step 2:

[image]

4. Continue with the Windows 10 setup
5. In the Windows VM, download and install SQL Server (I used [Express](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=52679))
6. When the SQL Server installation finishes, install the tool (SSMS) which we will need later

[image]

7. With SSMS, create a new database (I called mine `testdatabase`)

[image]

8.1. Create a new Login: right click on `Security > New > Login...`
Be sure to select the `SQL Server authentication` option.

[image]

8.2. In the `Server Roles` tab, select the `sysadmin` option:
[image]

8.3. In the `User Mapping` tab, map the login to the database, and check all assign the role memberships:

[image]

9. Open the server properties (right click the root level object).  Go to the `Security` tab, and switch the `Server Authentication mode` to `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode`:

[image]

10. Open the Windows Services program, and find the `SQL Server Browser`.  Open its properties and change the `Startup type` to automatic:

[image]

[image]

11.1. Open the Sql Server Configuration Manager program.  Navigate to the `Protocols` under the `SQL Server Network Configuration` and Enable the `TCP/IP` option:

[image]

11.2. Open the `TCP/IP` properties switch to the `IP Addresses tab`.  Make a note of the `IP Address` field under `IP2` (you will need this later):

[image]

11.3. Set the `TCP Port` under `IPALL` to `1433`:

[image]

12. Configure the Firewall on the Windows VirtualBox to allow 1433 to be unblocked (I just disabled the whole firewall, probably not the best option.) ***edit:*** *another user has kindly added the steps for adding a firewall rule to the end of this post*.
13. In your Macbook's VirtualBox app, open the settings for the Windows VM and go to the `Network` tab.  Set the `Attached to` dropdown to `NAT`, then click `Port Forwarding`.  Add a rule to forward the VM's 1433 port to your localhost's 1433 port.  The `Guest IP` will be the IP from Step 11.2:

[image]

---

You should now be able to connect to your SQLServer from your macbook with a connection string something like this:

`jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=testdatabase`

---

*Steps to open a port in the Windows firewall for TCP access*

1. On the **Start menu**, click **Run**, type **WF.msc**, and then click OK.
2. In the **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**, in the left pane, right-click **Inbound Rules**, and then click **New Rule** in the action pane (upper right corner).
3. In the **Rule Type** dialog box, select **Port**, and then click Next.
4. In the **Protocol and Ports** dialog box, select **TCP**. Select **Specific local ports**, and then type the port number of the instance of the Database Engine, In my case we are using the default which is **1433**. Click Next.
5. In the **Action** dialog box, select **Allow the connection**, and then click Next.
6. In the **Profile** dialog box, I am going to Leave Domain turned on and turn private and public off. Then click Next.
7. In the **Name** dialog box, type "Allow SQL 1433 Inbound" and for a description I am putting in the same. Then click Finish.

Comment: Works perfectly with windows host -> windows server guest !

Comment: Excellent tutorial!! helped me a lot!! on Step 3: SQL Server Browser Service must be started =)

Comment: Thank you for your excellent tutorial.
For sake of completeness here's how to set the Firewall to allow TCP on port 1433:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/06/how-to-open-firewall-port-1433-for-sql-server-database-engine-for-use-with-scom-or-anything-else/

Comment: I turned off the Firewall for _private_ networks but not _public_ and this caused me an issue when my host machine was at the library, etc. Rather than turning off the Firewall, I added an exception for SQL Server but again make sure that both public and private boxes are ticked!

Comment: It looks like the link @lwohlhart provided to a guide from MS about configuring the Windows firewall to allow traffic on port 1433 is dead. [Here is an updated link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-ver15#to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-firewall-for-tcp-access)

Comment: Should Guest IP follow a special rule?

Comment: I used an Ubuntu 20.04 VM, set up with Microsoft's quickstart guide ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16 ), then the final step in this guide. Success!