# Troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server from my .NET application.

I tried it on my pc and one other pc with already installed sql server.

I needed to test my app and I started virtual machines (windows 7 and 8.1).

I am constantly getting error:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)"

I tried everything that i found on internet that might help.
Nothing works for me.

Im using VirtualBox for virtual machines.
Is there might problem with that or even problem is because I'm trying to do it on VM. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is `Named Pipes` enabled? Can you connect to SQL Server through SSMS?

Comment: A few things to check. First, can you ping the server name you are using in the connection string from the machine the code is running on? Second, is the Sql Server setup to allow remote connections (under server properties -> Connections). If you create a .udl file and double click on it, you should be able to test connections to the server.

Comment: open sql server configuration manager and check browser service are ruining and then enable TCP and Name Pipes also. You can do that from configuration manager -> sql server client configuration -> Enabled protocol -> enable tcp and named pipe

Comment: Follow all these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37616522/3270427

Comment: Are your program and the SQL Server instance on the same machine, or is one of them on the base machine and the other in a VM? If the latter, have you configured the firewall appropriately (but don't do allowing connections to the internet in general)?

Comment: named pipes enabled, protocols are enabled, firewall exception added, they are running on same machine.

Comment: Is it problem in SQL Server Express?
I pretty sure it is supported in Express edition, but i need to ask, I run out of all other options :O

Answer (score 0):

Check this is this helps go to run -> sql server configuration manager then check sql server service are running and then client protocol enabled

[image]

Comment: ok and when you run sql server management studio are you able to connect ?

Comment: last thing can you check on whic account sql services are running on ?local or network . if on local change it to network (NT) . you can check this in configuration manager